# First find folder and use this as parameter for 7zip

Tags: bash, 7zip

First I need to find a foldername in the current folder. That is the reason for maxdepth. Then if I found the folder I need to extract it . Do you think it will work that way. Thanks in advance

```
folder =  $(find -maxdepth 1 -name "*zip.0*" -type d)
    7z x ${folder}
```

Is there also a way to get the name of the unzipped folder ? Has the 7z command a return value

Comment: `folder=$(find -maxdepth 1 -name "*zip.0*" -type d) && echo 7z "${folder#*./}"`   but me not having used `7z` so it just my assumption.

Comment: I need someone who has used 7z command

Comment: The shell syntax and find will work, try it and see the output. You need to read the 7z manual for that

Comment: Jetchisel fixed two typos you have in his comment : 1)  the spaces around the `=` and 2) the use of `${...}` instead of `$(...)` for the subshell. While he's unfamiliar with 7z and can't guarantee those corrections will be enough to make your command work, he's familiar with `bash` and knows your command won't work until you apply these two corrections. He's also formatted the output so that it wouldn't end in `/`, which might or might not be helpful to invoke the `7z` command

Comment: To clarify, do you want to extract all files from all 7-zip archives who's filenames contain "zip.0" for a named directory?